# swifty objective-c++ using std::variant

Tags: c++, ios, enums, std, objective-c++

In general I'm trying to use std::variant for creating a declarative "union enum" type I need for describing a location in a list (UITableView/UICollectionView et.al).

In Swift this is precisely what I need to do:

```
enum Location {
  case Header
  case Footer
  case Index(NSIndexPath)
}
```

My API either allows calling with the "header" location (Any combination of section and row 0), the footer (and combination of section and dynamic row number which is changing according to the section) , or a specific index path.

In c++ I believe there is a `std::variant` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant which allows this behavior:

I need to do this in Objective-C++ but getting compiler errors

```
enum class Location {
    Header,
    Footer
};

std::variant<Location,Index> location ; (NSIndexPath *)
```

When I try to include `#include (or #import) <variant>` I get a compiler error that `variant file not found` in XCode.

Any way to do this?

Comment: `std::variant` is a C++17 feature that may not be supported by the compiler you are using.

Comment: I'll accept your answer if you want to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::variant` is a feature included in the upcoming C++17 standard that is in the process of being finalized. Some compilers currently have support for this feature, but it is something you have to check.

If your compiler does currently support it, you may find it in the `std::experimental` namespace instead of directly in `std`.